# Coffeescript organization in my rails app: some js are not firing

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, webpacker

I'm trying to organize the js in my rails app.
I create an admin.js where I load all my js files

```
// load all images

import '../admin/images/init.js.erb';

// init global javascript
import '../admin/global/init';
import '../admin/global/app.menu';
import '../admin/global/app.input';

// init page specific javascript
import '../admin/page_specific/admin_home_index';
import '../admin/page_specific/admin_users_index';
import '../admin/page_specific/init';

// import vendor js
import 'datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js'
import 'datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive.js'
import 'datatables.net-select'
import 'datatables-bulma/js/dataTables.bulma';
```

I'm keeping separated global js, that are executed on every page, page specific js and vendor js.

In my global js I have the initialization

```
window.App ||= {}

App.init = ->

$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  App.init()
```

And one of the global script is

```
App.Menu =
  update: ->
    $(".navbar-burger").toggleClass("is-active");
    $(".navbar-menu").toggleClass("is-active");

$(document).on "click", "[data-behavior~=open-hamburger-menu]", =>
  App.Menu.update()
```

In my page specific js I have the init

```
class Init
 constructor: ->
   page = "#{$('body').data('page')}"
   @execute_page_js(page)
 execute_page_js: (page) ->
   if 'function' is typeof window.App[page]
     klass = window.App[page]
     new klass()

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
 new Init()
```

And then I have some class

```
class App.adminHomeIndex
  constructor: ->
    console.log 'test'
```

I cannot understand why this global script doesn't fire...
This is my global/app.input file and it doesn't work

```
App.Input =
  updateName: ->
    console.log 'cio'
    # $('.file-name').html(input.files[0].name) if input.files.length > 0

$('.file .file-input').on "change", ->
  console.log 'ciao'
  App.Input.updateName()
```

Why this behavior?
Is there something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready(function(){})`, or in CoffeeScript `$(document).ready ->`, I guess? Another thing to try would be to drop a `console.log('hello world')` statement in your CoffeeScript file after `App.init`. If 'hello world' doesn't print to the console, your files aren't loading correctly. If it does print, you have a jQuery issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I am guessing this does not work because you are using turbolinks, and the `$('.file .file-input')` will only activate if anything matching that selector is available on the page, when the js is run (so on first load).

Instead write your code as follows:

```
$(document).on "change", ".file .file-input", ->
```

This will capture any `change` on document-level and check if the selector applies. So this means the callback will always work as expected, regardless of the content on the page, which might/will be dynamically added later.